# Bulk insert using transactions is blocking UI on async process

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous, transactions, async-await

Trying to insert multiple records into a MySQL database using async/await and transactions, however it is still causing the UI to become frozen/unresponsive while in the loop.

Looking at the following code, what am I doing wrong or how can this be achieved so that the UI is still responsive during this process.

**The async method**

```
public static async Task AddRecords() {
    foreach ( string month in Months ) {
        await MakeTable( month );
        string query="INSERT INTO `"+month+"` ( Caller, Started, Dialed, DurationSec, DurationMin, Cost, Location, Switch ) VALUES (@Caller, @Started, @Dialed, @DurationSec, @DurationMin, @Cost, @Location, @Switch);";
        using ( MySqlConnection cn=new MySqlConnection( ConnectionString.ToString() ) ) {
            await cn.OpenAsync();
            using ( MySqlTransaction trans=cn.BeginTransaction() ) {
                using ( MySqlCommand cmd=new MySqlCommand( query, cn, trans ) ) {
                    cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
                    foreach ( Record r in CDR.Records ) {
                        if ( r.Started.ToString( "yyyy-MM" )==month ) {
                            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Caller", r.Caller );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Started", r.Started );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Dialed", r.Dialed );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@DurationSec", r.Duration );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@DurationMin", Math.Ceiling( r.Duration/60 ) );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Cost", r.Cost );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Location", r.Location );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Switch", r.Switch.ToString() );
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                    trans.Commit();
                }
            }
            await cn.CloseAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**A snippet on how this is being called :**

```
    private async void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
         this.Text = "Adding Records";
         await AddRecords();
         this.Text = "Completed";
    }
```

*As an aside, the when UI is blocking, shouldn't it block after all prior code has been executed. For example, in the above button click method, the first 'this.Text' is not set because as soon as `await AddRecords();` executes, it happens before the UI has a chance to finish updating, and doesn't complete until  after the blocking is finished which results in only `this.Text - "Completed"` being noticed at the UI level.*

---

**UPDATE**

UI is still blocking after modifying `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` to `await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();` ( recommended by [Yuval Itzchakov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31336190/3504007) ) which leads me to believe it is blocking on the `trans.Commit();` line or something to do with how the transaction is being built.

**Updated code**

```
public static async Task AddRecords() {
    foreach ( string month in Months ) {
        await MakeTable( month );
        string query="INSERT INTO `"+month+"` ( Caller, Started, Dialed, DurationSec, DurationMin, Cost, Location, Switch ) VALUES (@Caller, @Started, @Dialed, @DurationSec, @DurationMin, @Cost, @Location, @Switch);";
        using ( MySqlConnection cn=new MySqlConnection( ConnectionString.ToString() ) ) {
            await cn.OpenAsync();
            using ( MySqlTransaction trans=cn.BeginTransaction() ) {
                using ( MySqlCommand cmd=new MySqlCommand( query, cn, trans ) ) {
                    cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
                    foreach ( Record r in CDR.Records ) {
                        if ( r.Started.ToString( "yyyy-MM" )==month ) {
                            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Caller", r.Caller );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Started", r.Started );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Dialed", r.Dialed );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@DurationSec", r.Duration );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@DurationMin", Math.Ceiling( r.Duration/60 ) );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Cost", r.Cost );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Location", r.Location );
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Switch", r.Switch.ToString() );
                            await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                        }
                    }
                    trans.Commit();
                }
            }
            await cn.CloseAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of the time is spend in the `Commit` operation. The problem is that each `await` in your `AddRecords` function synchronizes back to the UI thread the function was called from. That is your main problem.

The easiest way to disconnect from this `SynchronizationContext` that causes you trouble is to force `AddRecords` to run in the `ThreadPool`-Thread.

Doing this is easy:

```
private async void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
     this.Text = "Adding Records";
     await Task.Run(() => AddRecords());
     this.Text = "Completed";
}
```

This will run your database stuff in the `ThreadPool` and only the `Task` you created here synchronizes back to the UI once everything is done.

The down side of this is, that you can't access the UI from within the `AddRecords` method anymore. But in your code you didn't do this, so I guess it is fine.

Comment: Thank you Nitram. I was considering implementing this way, however wanted to make sure that there was no way to do .Commit without blocking the UI.  I did notice there is a context for Commit, however it appears (unsure) to be only regarding how the table or records are locked.

Comment: Slight correction in your syntax as well. Instead of `await Task.Run(AddRecords);` it should be `await Task.Run(() => AddRecords());` if you wanted to update your post.

Comment: @SanuelJackson I am usually using VB.net, sorry for that. But I actually did not intent to create a lambda function there but reference a delegate function. Doesn't this work like that? Regarding the general answer: What are your concerns? The `AddRecords` function will work like before, with the advantage that the `await` does not sync to the UI but schedule the continuation in the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: Not a problem Nitram.  VB is my natural language.  Task.Run still requires a pointer to the method or whatever that syntax is called.  Also, in VB, I could always drop a sloppy .DoEvents() in between where I wish to 'force' UI updates :).  The method you proposed I am sure it should work (at least I think so as I was considering this as a last resort myself but havn't tested).  Since I am sure no one here is psychic, I will test this out and see if it does work as (we both think) is intended.

Comment: @SanuelJackson Actually I think with the `Task.Run` it is the "correct" way to do it, because you reduce the load on the UI Thread at the parts where the synchronization to the UI thread is not required. In your original version the synchronization to the UI is established again after every single query.

Comment: Let me restate that.  By hackish, I mean forcing implementation of something which that object should already have an implementation available.  Heres to hoping in the future that async/await drops async into a background thread automatically.   It does work, so I will accept this as the working solution, however I am still interested in making .Commit work without resorting to forcibly switching threads (even though it is rather trivial)  :)

Comment: I do not think that it should send anything into the background by force. There are cases where you need the outer synchronization context inside a function that is awaited (for updating the UI without using `DoEvents` that is **A LOT** more hacky.)

Answer (score 5):

Use `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`:

```
await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

That's the most time consuming call of your query, which is blocked synchronously because you're using the synchronous version.

**Edit:**

Since you don't need to do any UI work which requires a synchronization context, you can use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, You can apply that to `OpenAsync`, then the continuation will run on the threadpools IO workers.

Comment: UI is still blocking -.- .  I believe this is happening on the `Commit` as it seems to be the only thing left that isn't async.

Comment: @Sanuel Do you have a `CommitAsync` method?

Comment: Not that I can see.  Didn't notice anything like that, else would have used it.  Will check again though.  --- confirmed. No `CommitAsync()`

Comment: As noted --  it is quite unusual that all other important (and not so slow commands such as `CloseAsync()` or `OpenAsync()`) commands have an Async method, yet the one that needs it the most -- doesn't.  I find it hard to believe that something like this would be an oversight which leads me to reason that there must be a way to do transactions using async natively without resorting to hackish code such as creating a separate thread object or handling as `await Task.Run(()=>Function());` .

Comment: @Sanuel I couldn't agree more, but since I haven't done work with the `MySql` driver for C#, I'm not familiar with the proper way of consuming it. I would want to believe the implementers have thought about that. From the research I've done I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: I did a minimal compile and adjusted the namespace to be consumed in `System.Data.MySql` vs `MySqlClient.` as it seemed more logical. There were some adjustments, but I didn't notice anything regarding transactions as asynchronous methods. Something that I should consider later if I decide to modify the code base (at least internally anyway as I am not sure Oracle would enjoy a push request of this nature).  Took their large lib and shrunk down to under 400kb (uncompressed) after stripping the useless fat.

Comment: @Sanuel If IO is a large part of your application, perhaps you should reconsider the implementation of the database. Perhaps look for a driver which does expose async IO methods

Comment: @Sanuel See my edit to the answer. I think using `ConfigureAwait(false)` is less "hackish" than `Task.Run`